# Prevent deleted files from running in the Startup folder

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I have a batch script in my startup folder called everytime.bat that deletes all files except for the batch script.

```
@echo off
REM delete everything in startup except this file
cd "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
for %%i in (*.*) do if not "%%i"=="everytime.bat" del /s /q /f "%%i"
```

That part works fine. The problem is I added a text file to the startup folder to test this workflow and windows keeps trying to open the text file which no longer exists. Any way around this?

Comment: Have you removed the key from the registery, that attempts to open a file, that does not exist?

Comment: @Ramhound no I have not. Could you describe how one does that?

Comment: Autoruns makes that incredibly easy.  Have you attempted to use that program?

Comment: You really have subfolders in `...\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` ?

Comment: I don't have any subfolders, I am simply removing any files or applications in the Startup folder. However, after deleting them windows is still trying to run them

Comment: You can have viruses with more other files in other folders in a running infection cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substitution of `for` variable in argument too, where the argument `%0` is your `file.bat`:

```
    %~0   - expands %0 removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~f0  - expands %0 to a fully qualified path name only
    %~n0  - expands %0 to a file name only
    %~x0  - expands %0 to a file extension only

    %%~nx0 => expands %%~ to a file name and extension
```

Try using one more specific command to prevent delete your bat file using `%~nx0`:

```py
@echo off

REM delete everything in startup except this file
set "_Startup=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('where /r "%_Startup%" *.*^|findstr /vi "%~x0  Desktop.ini"')do echo\ del /q /f "%%~i"
```

> ```py
> where /r "%_Startup%" *.*
> List all files recursively in your folder: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
>
> ^|findstr /v /i "%~x0"
> /v == List all files NOT containing the file bat Name.eXtension (the same as %~nx0) and the hidden system file Desktop.ini  
> /i == Ignores the case UPPER/lower of characters when searching for the string.
> ```

---

**Obs.:** This folder has a hidden desktop.ini file, and if you already delete this `desktop.ini` file and want to restore it:

1. Open the notepad paste/save with the content below and name `desktop.ini`
   in the same folder:

```py
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21787
```

2. To return the hidden attribute, run:

```py
 attrib +r "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\desktop.ini"
```

---

- To make your bat file prevent the `desktop.ini` file from being deleted as well, you can substitute `find /v /i` for `findstr /vi`, and add `desktop.ini` as a multiple filter:

```py
@echo off

REM delete everything in startup except this file and desktop.ini
set "_Startup=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('where /r "%_Startup%" *.*^|findstr /vi "%~nx0 
 Desktop.ini"')do echo\ del /q /f "%%~i"
```

> ```py
> where /r "%_Startup%" *.*
> List all files recursively in your folder: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
>
> ^|findstr /vi "%~x0" is the same concatenate: /v /i
> /v == List all files NOT containing the file bat Name.eXtension, the same as %~nx0 also Desktop.ini
> /i == Ignores the case UPPER/lower of characters when searching for the string.
> ```

- **Note:** Test and check the output, if it looks correct, just remove the `echo\`:

```py
echo\ del /q /f "%%~i"
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Where](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**

  [√] **[Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

Comment: But will this prevent Windows from attempting to run files/applications in the Startup folder that were deleted?

Comment: @Kat  For sure, by deleting files in this folder...

Comment: @Kat there are many ways to load / execute files in the boot process beyond this folder, check [this out](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns), but be careful. Video [how to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7HZ1jzdEvk)

Comment: I did the last batch of code you added and now it's not deleting anything

Comment: @Kat Remove `echo \` ... this is there for you test, after see that's ok, remove it